# Haskell `sequence` function returns slightly different type than expected

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and playing around with some [code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tashmore/15352e736aea7ae212ff/raw/1202d50f1b27f60907fdb0c6a3dacf29b0a283e3/gistfile1.hs).
I was confused by the following GHCI session:

```
*Main> :l golden_cross_sample.hs
*Main> :t stateProcessors
stateProcessors :: [State GoldenCrossState String]
*Main> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
*Main> let res1 = (sequence stateProcessors)
*Main> :t res1
res1 :: StateT GoldenCrossState Identity [String]
```

From the type signature of `sequence`, I expected `res1` to have type `State GoldenCrossState [String]`. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does. `State s a` is a type synonym for `StateT s Identity a`, as you can read in [Haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:State).

Comment: FYI: This can be checked very easily with `:info State`, which will show the type alias definition in GHCi.